# Swig and Lua: how to map Lua file to FILE*

Tags: lua, swig

I have a C function that takes `FILE*` as an argument and I'd like to use this function in Lua, passing Lua file. I guess I need a `%typemap` for this. How to write it? 
(I just started learning Lua).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the solution that I finally came up with.

In Lua source, in liolib.c, there is a function `FILE *tofile (lua_State *L)`, which converts Lua file to C FILE*, but it's not a part of the API. I modified it a bit to make a typemap:

```
%typemap(in) FILE * {
    FILE **f;
    if (lua_isnil(L, $input))
        $1=NULL;
    else {
        f = (FILE **)luaL_checkudata(L, $input, "FILE*");
        if (*f == NULL)
            luaL_error(L, "attempt to use a closed file");
        $1=*f;
    }
}
```

This typemap accepts also nil, because I needed a way to pass NULL to the C function.

Answer (score 0):

You're using SWIG to generate Lua bindings for your C code?  Why not use the Lua C API directly, or if you can use C++, Luabind?  I think either of those would be better than trying to make it work with SWIG, unless you've got a strong attachment to SWIG already.

Comment: I'm generating Python bindings using SWIG, so I think the easiest way is to reuse the same .i file for Lua bindings. And it works fine, with the exception described in the question.

Thanks for pointing to other options.

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way to do what you're asking.

The Lua File class interface abstracts the underlying implementation. You cannot simply typemap it. You can, however, create a C proxy that wraps FILE operations you need and create an instance of this proxy in Lua using SWIG. You can then generate a typemap to convert a FILE* to a wrapper proxy instance.

Something like:

```
class MyFileProxy {
    private:
        FILE* fp;
    public:
        MyFileProxy(FILE* fp);
        MyFileProxy(const char* path); 

        FILE* GetFilePointer();

        Seek(...
```

In SWIG the binding is simply:

```
%module "MyFile"

%{
#include "MyFileProxy.h"
%}

// Tell SWIG how to use a proxy for functions that take a FILE*
%typemap(in) FILE*
{
    void* tmp = 0;
    SWIG_ConvertPtr(L,$argnum,(void**)&tmp,$1_descriptor,1);

    if (tmp)
    {
        MyFileProxy* proxy = (MyFileProxy)tmp;
        arg$argnum = proxy->GetFilePointer();
    }
}

// Tell SWIG how to create a proxy when returning FILE*
%typemap(out) FILE*
{
    MyFileProxy* pResult = new MyFileProxy($arg);
    SWIG_NewPointerObj(L, pResult, $1_descriptor, 1);
}

%include "MyFileProxy.h 

}
```

You won't be able to use io:File directly, however.